# SOQL query to fetch incremental data hourly

Tags: soql, datetime, query

I am using Jitterbit to confirgure data transfer to and fro my MySQL database. My requirement is such that I need to fetch newly created records from Salesforce into my database every hour.

For this purpose,I have been searching time functions like `NOW()` or `SYSDATE` to go in my `WHERE` clause, however, I could not find any.

Can someone please suggest a work around or a native function to serve the purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In SOQL there is a built in syntax for LAST_N_DAYS, but for this case your will have to construct a date literal string (see [Date Formats and Date Literals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)) so your query becomes e.g.:

```
SELECT Id, ... FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate > 2005-10-08T01:02:03Z
```

Note that no quotes are used.

Jitterbit appears to have [functions to produce formatted dates](http://www.jitterbit.com/Docs/WebHelp/Formula_Builder/DateTime_Functions.htm) but I don't know whether they can be injected into the query string.